# How to receive video call events in ASP.NET for Twilio Video

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio, twilio-api

I am creating a webhook for the status callback for video calls with Twilio. The issue is that I want to filter events that occur so that I can do some other things with that information. How do I receive those events when I create a video call?

Comment: Hi, if I understand you correctly, you already have a working webhook, but it does not receive HTTP requests for when a video call is created, is that correct?
Could you clarify what you have now and where you want to go?

Comment: Hello, I am trying to get my webhook to work. I have an POST endpoint which is called when room is created. However that endpoint is empty as I am not sure how to read data that twilio sends.                                                                                     On their site they have: All HTTP requests set the "Content-Type" header to “application/x-www-form-urlencoded”; so I assume I need to read that data somehow in my webhook endpoint but not sure how. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Got it! Let me try to put a sample together for that and answer. Are you using ASP.NET on .NET Framework or ASP.NET Core?

Btw, not sure who downvoted, but I'd recommend adding those details in your question and add the relevant code you have so far. With those details you usually get more upvotes and less downvotes.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is ASP .net core. Also thank you for tips for the future :)

Comment: You are most welcome! Please consider updating this question as well if you can.
It'll help other people find your question and this answer.
For example, the same question was just asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71794384/how-to-read-events-that-come-from-twilio-webhook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core you can handle webhooks using **MVC** or **Minimal APIs** (Endpoints).

---

MVC controllers are able to bind the form parameters to strongly-typed object parameters (also called model binding) or to simple parameters.

Here's a controller that will bind the form parameters to an instance of `RoomStatusRequest` and then log some of its properties:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using RoomStatusCallback.Models;

namespace RoomStatusCallback.Controllers;

public class RoomController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<RoomController> logger;

    public RoomController(ILogger<RoomController> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public ActionResult Status(RoomStatusRequest statusRequest)
    {
        logger.LogInformation(@"Room created
Name: {RoomName}
Sid: {RoomSid}
Status: {RoomStatus}
Type: {RoomType}",
            statusRequest.RoomName,
            statusRequest.RoomSid,
            statusRequest.RoomStatus,
            statusRequest.RoomType
        );
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

You can create the `RoomStatusRequest` class anywhere in your project:

```cs
namespace RoomStatusCallback.Models;

public class RoomStatusRequest
{
    public string AccountSid { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public string RoomSid { get; set; }
    public string RoomStatus { get; set; }
    public string RoomType { get; set; }
    public string StatusCallbackEvent { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

The form parameters will differ depending on the type of event you're receiving, so you'll need to add/remove properties depending on your needs. **This class is not all-encompassing to bind all status events properties**.

Alternatively, you can have MVC bind to simple parameters like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using RoomStatusCallback.Models;

namespace RoomStatusCallback.Controllers;

public class RoomController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<RoomController> logger;

    public RoomController(ILogger<RoomController> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public ActionResult Status(
        string roomName,
        string roomSid,
        string roomStatus,
        string roomType
    )
    {
        logger.LogInformation(@"Room created
Name: {RoomName}
Sid: {RoomSid}
Status: {RoomStatus}
Type: {RoomType}",
            roomName,
            roomSid,
            roomStatus,
            roomType
        );
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Whether you configured the StatusCallbackMethod as **POST** or **GET**, MVC will bind it from the **form parameters** or **query string parameters** respectively.

---

For Minimal APIs (Endpoints), you can accept the parameters like this for **POST** requests:

```
app.MapPost("/minimal/room/status", async (HttpRequest request) =>
{
    var form = await request.ReadFormAsync();

    var roomName = form["RoomName"];
    var roomSid = form["RoomSid"];
    var roomStatus = form["RoomStatus"];
    var roomType = form["RoomType"];
    app.Logger.LogInformation(@"Room created
Name: {RoomName}
Sid: {RoomSid}
Status: {RoomStatus}
Type: {RoomType}",
        roomName,
        roomSid,
        roomStatus,
        roomType
    );

    return Results.Ok();
});
```

Grab the form from the request, and then use string indexing to retrieve individual parameters.

And for **GET** requests:

```cs
app.MapGet("/minimal/room/status", (
    [FromQuery] string roomName,
    [FromQuery] string roomSid,
    [FromQuery] string roomStatus,
    [FromQuery] string roomType
) =>
{
    app.Logger.LogInformation(@"Room created
Name: {RoomName}
Sid: {RoomSid}
Status: {RoomStatus}
Type: {RoomType}",
        roomName,
        roomSid,
        roomStatus,
        roomType
    );

    return Results.Ok();
});

app.Run();
```

You can use individual parameter binding like in MVC. You don't need to specify `[FromQuery]` but I like to do so. If you don't use `[FromQuery]`, ASP.NET will also look in the route values, headers, and more to bind to your parameters.

For all the samples above, the parameter and property names have to match those in the form parameters, although you can use certain attributes to change that, but I'd advise to research [MVC Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and [Minimal API Parameter Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#parameter-binding) to learn more about that.

You can find the [source code for these samples and a sample to create the video room in this GitHub repository](https://github.com/Swimburger/TwilioVideoCallback).