# How to read events that come from twilio webhook?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I am creating a Video room on twilio and I created a webhook endpoint to where twilio sends events. One issue is that I don’t know how to read those events since twilio documentation on status callback doesn’t have any examples on how it actually works.

What is the best way to read that data since my endpoint looks something like this

```
Public async Task<IActionResult> statuscallbackwebhook(){
//read data that is recieved from twilio
}
```

Comment: Luckily, we just answered this exact question over here, I hope this helps!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71786461/2919731

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC on .NET Framework or ASP.NET Core MVC?

Comment: Hello, I am using asp.net core but I am not sure that what you wrote works for me. Status callback uri is set when room resource is created and it is my custom webhook that i created. Does my webhook need to accept any parameters  or no ? I am very confused since i can debug using ngrok and my webhook endpoint is triggered but not sure how to read the actual events that twilio sends to it. I would need to read data that twilio sends directly like room created, participant connected, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test this out, I created a [console app to create rooms for Twilio Video](https://github.com/Swimburger/TwilioVideoCallback/blob/main/CreateRoom/Program.cs) where you can specify the `statusCallback`:

```cs
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Video.V1;
using HttpMethod = Twilio.Http.HttpMethod;

// make sure to configure your Twilio Account SID and Auth Token as environment variables before running this program
var accountSid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TwilioAccountSid");
var authToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TwilioAuthToken");

TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

Console.Write("What is the room status callback URL?");
var roomStatusCallbackUrl = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine();

await RoomResource.CreateAsync(
    statusCallback: new Uri(roomStatusCallbackUrl), 
    statusCallbackMethod: HttpMethod.Post
);
```

Whatever way you are creating rooms, make sure to configure the `statusCallback` to the route that will match your controller-action.

Then in your controller action, you can accept the webhook parameters in two ways: using a strongly-typed object as a parameter, or using simple type parameters like `string`, `int`, `DateTime`, etc.

If you want to bind the webhook request parameters to a strongly-typed object, use the following code:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using RoomStatusCallback.Models;

namespace RoomStatusCallback.Controllers;

public class RoomController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<RoomController> logger;

    public RoomController(ILogger<RoomController> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public ActionResult Status(RoomStatusRequest statusRequest)
    {
        logger.LogInformation(@"Room created
Name: {RoomName}
Sid: {RoomSid}
Status: {RoomStatus}
Type: {RoomType}",
            statusRequest.RoomName,
            statusRequest.RoomSid,
            statusRequest.RoomStatus,
            statusRequest.RoomType
        );
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Then add the class which defines the properties of your strongly-typed object which have to match names with the names of the webhook request parameters. The [webhook request parameters for video room status are documented here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/status-callbacks#rooms-event-parameters). Here's the class I created to get data for the `room-created` status:

```cs
namespace RoomStatusCallback.Models;

public class RoomStatusRequest
{
    public string AccountSid { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public string RoomSid { get; set; }
    public string RoomStatus { get; set; }
    public string RoomType { get; set; }
    public string StatusCallbackEvent { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Feel free to add/remove properties as needed by your application. [ASP.NET Core MVC's model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0) will bind the webhook request parameters to the properties of your strongly-typed object.

The second way is to use simple type parameters like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using RoomStatusCallback.Models;

namespace RoomStatusCallback.Controllers;

public class RoomController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<RoomController> logger;

    public RoomController(ILogger<RoomController> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public ActionResult Status(
        string roomName,
        string roomSid,
        string roomStatus,
        string roomType
    )
    {
        logger.LogInformation(@"Room created
Name: {RoomName}
Sid: {RoomSid}
Status: {RoomStatus}
Type: {RoomType}",
            roomName,
            roomSid,
            roomStatus,
            roomType
        );
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The result is exactly the same, but by adding parameters to the action, ASP.NET Core's binding features will bind the webhook request parameters to the parameters of the action, as long as they match names.

To test this out using [the sample](https://github.com/Swimburger/TwilioVideoCallback):

1. Start the ASP.NET Core project containing your webhook
2. Start the ngrok tunnel service
3. Run the console app and pass in the public ngrok forwarding URL + the route to your controller-action.

There are even more ways to do this, but for MVC controller-actions, these two options would be the recommended way.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I tried you solution but it is still not quite working. My endpoint is never hit so I can't debug it. I am getting:                                                
POST /api/twilio/statuscallback 502 Bad Gateway                                 
POST /api/twilio/statuscallback 502 Bad Gateway                                 
POST /api/twilio/statuscallback 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: Interesting. You are using ngrok to tunnel your private server publicly, right?
You can inspect the HTTP requests and responses that are coming through the tunnel at http://127.0.0.1:4040/inspect/http. That's part of ngrok's local dashboard.
Can you share the RAW request and response from the dashboard?

Comment: Hello, I first get 415 unsupported media type and here is the raw from ngrock: HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Date: Mon, 11 Apr 2022 07:26:07 GMT
Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 175

{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"00-bd4b92a791312a4284f2a3b359f3e29a-eada6ee8f1bb3542-00"}

Comment: It was missing [FromForm] in the Webhook controller, after adding that I am getting events and other information about the room status. Thank you !!!

Comment: ASP.NET Core MVC's model binding should bind it for you with or without the attribute, but using the attribute makes it more explicit and will stop the model binder from considering other sources, so it's a good idea to add it. Glad it works!